# Clean way to add some components angular

Tags: angular

At the moment we have something like

```
<line-one>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == BatMan> <bat-man-comp/> <div>
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == SuperMan> <super-man-comp/> <div>
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == SpiderMan> <spider-man-comp/> <div>
    </div>
<line-one>

<line-two>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == BatMan> <bat-man-comp/> <div>
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == SuperMan> <super-man-comp/> <div>
     <div *ngIf= hero.name == SpiderMan> <spider-man-comp/> <div>
    </div>
<line-two>
```

I found this way of doing pretty cumbersome. But Angular seems to steer people away from the idea of adding components dynamically with typescript ( using ElementRef )

In this case, what is the best way to make the code cleaner?

- Edit : The hero components are wildly different and can not be refactored into one single component

Comment: As a minor improvement, I can suggest you use ngSwitch instead of these ngIf

Comment: You should create a component `<hero-comp>` which will `ngSwitchCase` hero names.

Answer (score 1):

For maintainability it would be best to create a generic component e.g. `hero-component` and provide the name as an @Input() for that. Then you can change what the component displays / it's behaviour based on what type of hero it is, since (i'm assuming) most heros will do similar things.

e.g.

```
<line-two>
    <div *ngFor="let hero of heroes">
     <hero-component [heroName]="hero.name"></hero-component>
    </div>
<line-two>
```

Where you check `heroName` inside your `hero-component`.

Hope this helps :)

Edit:
Have a look at and digest this design pattern. It should help your understanding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern